# Calculate total length of edges in select Voronoi diagram

Tags: computational-geometry

I want to calculate the total length of edges in a Voronoi diagram like this
[image: Voronoi]

I can calculate this with

```
lengths = RegionMeasure /@ MeshPrimitives[VoronoiMesh[pts], 1];

Total[lengths]
```

but, I want to eliminate from the calculation the diagrams touching the border of the image. I can select this diagrams like here

[image: Voronoi interior]

and I can keep with the orange diagrams

[image: selected cells]

but I don't know how to calculate the total length of the edges of the last graphic. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add the code to select the inner cells and the definition of `pts`?

Comment: The distribution of points pts comes from a picture but could be random numbers. For example:

SeedRandom[332]
pts = RandomReal[1, {100, 2}];

xy = VoronoiMesh[pts, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];

i2 = MeshCellIndex[xy, {2, "Interior"}] ;

HighlightMesh[xy, Style[i2, LightOrange]]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomReal[1, {100, 2}];
vm = VoronoiMesh[pts];
```

#### "Interior"

```
HighlightMesh[vm, Style[MeshCellIndex[vm, {1, "Interior"}], Red]]
```

[image]

```
Total[ArcLength /@ MeshPrimitives[vm , {1, "Interior"}]]
```

> 19.4739

Alternatively,

```
Total[RegionMeasure /@ MeshPrimitives[vm, {1, "Interior"}]]
```

> 19.4739

```
RegionMeasure[MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[vm], MeshCells[vm, {1, "Interior"}]]]
```

> 19.4739

#### "Boundary"

```
HighlightMesh[vm, Style[MeshCellIndex[vm, {1, "Boundary"}], Red]]
```

[image]

```
Total[ArcLength /@ MeshPrimitives[vm, {1, "Boundary"}]]
```

> 5.92015

#### "Frontier"

```
HighlightMesh[vm, Style[MeshCellIndex[vm, {1, "Frontier"}], Red]]
```

[image]

```
Total[ArcLength /@ MeshPrimitives[vm, {1, "Frontier"}]]
```

> 5.357575

#### All lines

```
Total[vm["EdgeLengths"]]
```

> 30.75167

```
Total[ArcLength /@ MeshPrimitives[vm , 1]]
```

> 30.751672460568727

Comment: So long as none of the cells adjacent to the boundary aren't in fact the full Voronoi cell. This would only happen in contrived cases though.

Comment: @ChipHurst, good point.

Comment: I am impressed by the speed and clarity in your response, kglr. I am very grateful with you. Thank you.

Comment: @MatiGer, my pleasure. Thank you for the kind words and accept.