# Get interior of mesh region

Tags: regions, mesh, discretization

I really like the functionality of Mathematica for mesh-based regions,
and have enough understanding of it. But this problem bothers me.
There is [a similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154544/interior-of-discretized-region), but the functionality used now obsolete.

Let we have mesh region (for simplicity `MeshCellMeasure` made large enough):

```
region = DiscretizeRegion[Annulus[{0, 0}, {1/2, 1}, {0,3 Pi/2}], {MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.15}, ImageSize -> 150}]
```

[image]

I need to separate *the interior* — all that is **not** `RegionBoundary@region`.
And in the form in which it is obtained at primary discretization;
literally everything that is not highlighted red:

```
bound = RegionBoundary@region;
Show[region, 
 HighlightMesh[
  bound, {Style[1, Red], Style[0, PointSize[Medium], Red]}]]
```

[image]

I was only able to do it this way:

```
coords = MeshCoordinates@region;
boundCoords = MeshCoordinates@bound;
verts = Range@Length@coords;
boundVerts = Flatten[Position[coords, #] & /@ boundCoords, 2];
interior = 
 ConcaveHullMesh[coords[[Delete[verts, Partition[boundVerts, 1]]]]]
```

[image]

In fact, it is simplest form of *erosion*, but I can't get it nor with `RegionErosion` nor with `Erosion`.

I’m sure it can be made simpler and more contemporary,
thanks for help in advice!

Comment: How about `interior = RegionDifference[region, bound]`?

Comment: @user64494, it makes solid region without mesh. I need to preserve mesh from initial region!

Comment: @lesobrod The "interior" is the remaining mesh when all boundary lines are removed?

Comment: Boundary lines and vertices

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
interior = {interiorpoints, interiorlines, interiorpolygons} = 
   MeshCells[region, {#, "Interior"}] & /@ {0, 1, 2};

HighlightMesh[region, interior, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
Row[HighlightMesh[region, ToExpression@#, 
   ImageSize -> Medium, PlotLabel -> Style[#, 20]] & /@ 
 {"interiorpoints", "interiorlines", "interiorpolygons"}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], RandomColor[], #} & /@ 
   MeshPrimitives[region, {2, "Interior"}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting answer ! Where did you find the option `"Interior"`? `Options[MeshCells]` gives `{}`! Thanks

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, afaik these  syntaxes/properties  are not documented. I don't remember how I bumped into things like `{1,"Interior"}` , `{2, "Frontier"}` , `{0,"Boundary"}` as valid  cell indices. (I played with the list returned by `mesh["Properties"]` (where `mesh` is a `MeshRegion` or a `BoundaryMeshRegion` object) and found some properties can be accessed using these propery names.) related: [Boundary cells of a mesh?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134634/125), [total length of edges in select Voronoi diagram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/192835/125)

Comment: Thanks for YouTube helpfull Auswertung!

Comment: @kglr, OMG, I play sometimes with `"Properties"`, but there are lot of non documented for `MeshRegion`...  Even `"DeepCopy"`  (o_O)  
Thank you anyway, that works for version 12, 13 and 14 very well!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to remove only the faces that have an edge on the boundary. This differs from `MeshCells[region, {2, "Interior"}]` since that also excludes faces with only a point touching the boundary.

```
g = MeshConnectivityGraph[region, {1, 2}, 1];

bdedges = Pick[VertexList[g], VertexDegree[g], 1];
bdfaces = VertexOutComponent[g, bdedges, {1}][[All, 2]];
interiorfaces = Complement[Range[MeshCellCount[region, 2]], bdfaces];

submesh = MeshRegion[
  MeshCoordinates[region], 
  MeshCells[region, {2, interiorfaces}]
]
```

[image]

```
HighlightMesh[region, {2, interiorfaces}]
```

[image]